# Creating a connect wallet button like JPEG.store

Tags: wallet, decentralized-applications

I am creating a React app and I want to integrate a connect wallet button that can then return the users wallet address, similar to JPEG.store. What is the best way to approach this. I tried using Cardano connect with wallet https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-connect-with-wallet but I cant figure out how to return the users address after they have signed in with their wallet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved by variety of tools:

1. Using Lucid, you can first enable (connect) with wallet as outlined in [this](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid#basic-usage) simple example. Then get address via `lucid.wallet.address()` (it returns a `Promise`, so you might need to use `async / await`). This address is basically obtained from [CIP-30](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/#apigetusedaddressespaginatepaginateundefinedpromiseaddress)'s, `getUsedAddresses()`'s first element.
2. Like what you have shared in question, Mesh has a prebuilt component for it, which can be seen [here](https://mesh.martify.io/react/ui-components). Once connected, you can get address as mentioned in [this](https://mesh.martify.io/apis/browserwallet) page.
3. Regarding library in question, can use [`decodeHexAddress`](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-connect-with-wallet/blob/main/src/utils/wallet.ts#L19) on browser wallet api's, `getUsedAddresses()`'s first element.